# How can I use Autocomplete with c#.net AJAX textbox textchanged event?

Tags: c#, jquery, events, autocomplete

I'm having a pretty nasty problem with C#.Net Textbox textchanged event, AJAX and AutoComplete (https://github.com/devbridge/jQuery-Autocomplete)

I have a Textbox "Flight Number" with AutoComplete functioning. Once a suggestion is selected, I would want to use AJAX and update "Departure Airport" (DDL) and "Destination Airport" (DDL).

Problem: When I selected any suggestion from the AutoComplete, the Flight Number does not post back with the selected suggestion value. For example, if I typed "G91", and click on "G9101", "G9101" will appear on the Flight Number Textbox for a split second, and then resets to "G91" because of AutoPostBack. How can I let it post back the suggested value?

**UPDATE**: I got it solved, but the AutoComplete does not work after the first post back.

Flight Number Textbox

```
<div class="split half last">
                <label for="calculator-flight-number">
                    Flight Number</label>
                <asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel7" runat="server">
                    <ContentTemplate>
                        <div id="autocomplete-wrap" class="autocomplete-wrap">
                            <asp:TextBox ID="tbFlightNumber" runat="server"  ClientIDMode="Static" CssClass="fill" ontextchanged="tbFlightNumber_TextChanged" AutoPostBack="true"></asp:TextBox>
                        </div>
                    </ContentTemplate>
                    <Triggers>
                        <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="bnCalculate" EventName="Click" />
                    </Triggers>
                </asp:UpdatePanel>
            </div>
```

Airports DDL

```
<div class="split fill last">
                <label class="fill" for="calculator-departure">
                    Departure</label>
                <asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel13" runat="server">
                    <ContentTemplate>
                        <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlDepartureAirport" CssClass="split threequarters" runat="server">
                        </asp:DropDownList>
                    </ContentTemplate>
                    <Triggers>
                        <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="bnCalculate" EventName="Click" />
                        <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="tbFlightNumber" EventName="TextChanged" />
                    </Triggers>
                </asp:UpdatePanel>
            </div>
            <div class="split fill last">
                <asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel14" runat="server">
                    <ContentTemplate>
                        <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlDestinationAirport" CssClass="split threequarters" runat="server">
                        </asp:DropDownList>
                    </ContentTemplate>
                    <Triggers>
                        <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="bnCalculate" EventName="Click" />
                        <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="tbFlightNumber" EventName="TextChanged" />
                    </Triggers>
                </asp:UpdatePanel>
            </div>
```

Javascript

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var options, a;
jQuery(function () {
    options = {
        serviceUrl: '/Service/FlightSector',
        appendTo: 'div#autocomplete-wrap' 
    };
    console.log($('#tbFlightNumber'));
    a = $('#tbFlightNumber').autocomplete(options);
});
```

1st try:

I did the usual AJAX way, and did TextChanged event for Flight Number. I was hoping that when I click the suggestion from AutoComplete, AJAX would fire and update the 2 Airports. AJAX did not fire. I switched on "AutoPostBack" for Flight Number, and only the first character from the entire suggestion box is posted back. For e.g. If "G" is type, suggestion would show "G1002". When G1002 is clicked as a selection from Autocomplete, only G would be posted back.

2nd try:

I used javascript "OnBlur" method and manually handled the post back.

```
//for flight number postback
protected void Page_Init(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var onBlurScript = Page.ClientScript.GetPostBackEventReference(tbFlightNumber, "OnBlur");
    tbFlightNumber.Attributes.Add("onblur", onBlurScript);
}

private void HandleCustomPostbackEvent(string ctrlName, string args)
{
    //Since this will get called for every postback, we only
    // want to handle a specific combination of control
    // and argument.
    if (ctrlName == tbFlightNumber.UniqueID && args == "OnBlur")
    {
        string flightNumber = tbFlightNumber.Text;
        ....
        //update 2 airports DDL
    }
}
```

This does not work, because I could not get AJAX to register the trigger for the 2 drop down lists. Also, the selection of the autocomplete suggestion would trigger the "onblur".

3rd try:
I tried with onfocus instead for the next field, but it does not work with the same reason.

I am sort of stuck here, can anyone show me some pointers? TIA.

Comment: post html and javacript code

Comment: Updated the codes with front end AJAX element and javascript.

Comment: your jquery autocomplete not workig right:

Comment: The jquery autocomplete is working perfectly. It is just that I cannot get it to autoload airport once a suggestion is clicked.

Comment: where is your select event of autocomplete

Comment: the way you doing i think it will not gonna work, there is a select event of autocomplete in that you have to do this by using Ajax Handler of asp.net

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using Update Panel then you will have an issue and it will not work after first server call. To solve this issue you need to add PageRequestManager PageLoad Event to load the content again.

Add the bottom of your page before  tag add:

```
Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManager.getInstance().add_pageLoaded(AddHandler);
function AddHandler(sender,args)
{
var options = {
        serviceUrl: '/Service/FlightSector',
        appendTo: 'div#autocomplete-wrap' 
    };
    console.log($('#tbFlightNumber'));
    var a = $('#tbFlightNumber').autocomplete(options);
}
```

Hopefully this should work.

I was having the same issue and that's how I have solved my problem.